# Do I have to use some kind of index to use WHERE in Rails5 ActiveRecord?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I use Rails 5 and Postgres.

I have a table ZipRanges with the columns id, region_id, from, to

I want to select all rows where a given zip code is between from and to.

```
zip = 1234
ZipRange.where("from < ?", zip).where("to > ?", zip)
```

I get the following error:

> ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error
>   at or near "from"

Do I have to use some kind of index to be able to make this query?

I tried other queries and they work fine. For example:

```
ZipRange.where("region_id = ?", 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

`From` is a [reserved word](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/sql-keywords-appendix.html) in Postgres(and I would guess other databases as well) and therefore you get this error. But the main reason is you're setting your query up incorrectly.

You have to format your query like this.

```
ZipRange.where('zip >= :from AND zip <= :to', from: 1, to: 100)
```

You can also be a bit fancy and do

```
ZipRange.where(zip: 1..100)
```

Which also works with variables

```
from = params[:from]
to = params[:to]
ZipRange.where(zip: from..to)
```

EDIT:
In light of the comment below, here is one more version

```
ZipRange.where('from_column > :zip AND to < :zip', zip: 100)
```

Change `from_column` to your new column name.

Comment: `ZipRange.where(zip: 1..100)` creates `WHERE zip BETWEEN 1 AND 100` which can be more performant.

Comment: The hint with the reserved words was great. I just changed my column names. Please note, that I don't have a column zip and want to find the row where zip is between two values. The table has the columns from and to and I want to fin the row where these two columns are bigger and smaller than a given zip.